# Angular/ Protractor E2E Test fails when run in Azure DevOps Pipeline. Passes locally

Tags: javascript, angular, selenium, protractor, azure-devops

I am trying to run e2e tests on my angular application. My tests pass locally when I run `ng e2e` but not in my pipeline. I'm going to share my protractor.conf, the pipeline tasks and the output I get from the task that fails below.

Some more background:

- I am trying to run e2e code from an otherwise empty angular app. The
  test I am trying to run simply logs into AD by navigating to my
  website, entering a username/ password and then checking the that the
  user is redirected to my website.
- I am running this from a release
  pipeline where the repo containing the e2e tests is added as an
  artifact.
- I am using xpaths to find elements on the page
- I've omitted my jasmine code because I do not think it is relevant since the tests pass locally. However, if I'm wrong on this point let me know and I will post it.

**protractor.conf.js**

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

process.env.CHROME_BIN = process.env.CHROME_BIN || require("puppeteer").executablePath();

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1200,900"],
      binary: process.env.CHROME_BIN
    },
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

**Pipeline Tasks:**
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Failed Task Output:
[image]

Please help me get these tests to pass in azure

Thanks!

EDIT: I have that 'Update Webdriver' task because I read I should do it somewhere, it doesn't actually change the outcome if it is there or not

Comment: could you share your test file?

Comment: Please check the chromedriver.exe (in your log, you installed `chromedriver 2.4`6) is compatible with the chrome.  If you not specify environment `CHROME_BIN` ,  you use the chrome supplied by package `puppeteer`, find the chrome binary from this package and check its version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to increase your ***allScriptsTimeout***?

> The timeout in milliseconds for each script run on the browser. This should be longer than the maximum time your application needs to stabilize between tasks.